# Cant' put number in value of text input using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list that has several option. I dynamically set an event that whenever a button is clicked, create a table and text input and put the value of list in in there, but I have option that have number value but it didn't set to the value of that input. See my code.

My jquery code:

```
$("#table_drugs").append("<tr><td>"
    + $("#drugs_list").val() + "<input type='text' name='past_druges_used' value="+$("#drugs_list").val()+">"
    + "</td><td>" + $("#drugs-explain").val()+"<input type='text' name='how_to_use' value="+$("#drugs-explain").val()+">"
    + "</td><td>" + "<button type='button' class='col-sm-7 btn btn-danger pull-right'>delete</button> "
    + "</td></tr>");
```

And my html:

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="drugs_list_div" class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-6">
                <select id="drugs_list" class="form-control" style="font-family: font-style-3;">
                    <option>empty</option>
                    <option>Drugs 1</option>
                    <option>Drugs 3</option>
                    <option>Drugs 2</option>

                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="drugs-explain-div" class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="drugs-explain" style="font-family: font-style-1;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="table-drugs-div" class="col-xs-11 list-hide">
                <table class="table table-striped" id="table_drugs">
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I can't get U what do you mean by mkay!!!

Comment: Sorry man.. I do not understand your question, sorry i can't help.. So i decided to try and make people laugh

Comment: @3rror404 I suspect you haven't understood what it's supposed to do, then. It definitely doesn't work if you select an option with a space in its text from the dropdown.

Comment: @MarkRijsmus Don't worry I got my answer and sorry for using drugs :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put quotes around your values:

```
$("#table_drugs").append("<tr><td>"
    + $("#drugs_list").val() + "<input type='text' name='past_druges_used' value='"+$("#drugs_list").val()+"'>"
    + "</td><td>" + $("#drugs-explain").val()+"<input type='text' name='how_to_use' value='"+$("#drugs-explain").val()+"'>"
    + "</td><td>" + "<button type='button' class='col-sm-7 btn btn-danger pull-right'>delete</button> "
    + "</td></tr>");
```

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote - I think you'll find this solves the problem, which is caused by the space in the value of the option and not having quotes around the value in the input

Comment: Yes its not just for number if we don't put quotes around value it don't see space and just one work cant put in input thank anyway :)